# How to check if the string matches a regex

Tags: regex, ruby

I am learning regex, using:

- https://blog.arkency.com/the-equals-equals-equals-case-equality-operator-in-ruby/
- https://www.rubyguides.com/2015/06/ruby-regex/

I have clear information and was running happily with the tutorials until I kicked the stone:

```
rule = /^[0-9][a-z]$/

puts "rb -------------------------"
p "rb".match? rule #=> false
p !!("rb" =~ rule) #=> false
p "rb" === rule #=> false

puts "1t -------------------------"
p "1t".match? rule #=> true
p !!("1t" =~ rule) #=> true
p "1t" === rule #=> false
```

Can someone explain why the last one is false?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`===` is the subsumption operator, where `big_concept === specific_concept` tests whether the `big_concept` subsumes the `specific_concept`. With regular expressions, you want to test whether the class of strings described by a regular expression subsumes a specific string; so you would write it as `rule === "1t"`. This usage is described at [`RegExp#===`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D).

`"1t" === rule` tests whether the string `"1t"` subsumes the regular expression; but strings only subsume (by Ruby's rules) objects that are identical to the string when stringified (with `to_s`). `rule` stringifies to `"(?-mix:^[0-9][a-z]$)"`, which is different from `"1t"`, therefore `false`. This usage is described at [`String#===`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/String.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D).

With that, here's your code, corrected (and expanded :D ):

```
rule = /^[0-9][a-z]$/

puts "rb -------------------------"
p "rb".match? rule #=> false
p !!("rb".match? rule) #=> false
p !!("rb" =~ rule) #=> false
p !("rb" !~ rule) #=> false
p rule === "rb" #=> false
p !!("rb"[rule]) #=> false
p rule.match? "rb" #=> false
p !!(rule.match "rb") #=> false

puts "1t -------------------------"
p "1t".match? rule #=> true
p !!("1t".match rule) #=> true
p !!("1t" =~ rule) #=> true
p !("1t" !~ rule) #=> true
p rule === "1t" #=> true
p !!("1t"[rule]) #=> true
p rule.match? "1t" #=> true
p !!(rule.match "1t") #=> true
```